# Compatibility of tikzmark and chappg

Tags: page-numbering, tikzmark

I have encountered a strange problem when using `tikzmark` and `chappg` in a document:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 

\usepackage{chappg}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test} 

foo\tikzmark{foo}

\vspace{2cm}

bar\tikzmark{bar}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
   \draw (pic cs:foo) -- (pic cs:bar); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This yields

```
l.21    \draw (pic cs:foo)
                           -- (pic cs:bar);

      ! Missing number, treated as zero.
```

on the second run. If I delete the `aux` file and compile it without `chappg`, everything works fine. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stefan mentions in [`his answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262664/3954), there seems to be a problem with `tikzmark`; in

```
execute at end picture={%
\ifpgfrememberpicturepositiononpage%
\edef\pgf@temp{%
\noexpand\write\noexpand\pgfutil@auxout{%
\string\savepicturepage{\pgfpictureid}{\noexpand\thepage}}}%
\pgf@temp
\fi%
},
```

it uses `\thepage` and it's safer to use `\value{page}`. Here's a corrected version (there's also a `\thepage` in the definition of `\pgfmark`, but since it's not used here, it's not relevant here, although it should also be changed):

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 

\usepackage{chappg}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
remember picture with id/.style={%
remember picture,
overlay,
save picture id=#1,
},
every picture/.append style={%
execute at end picture={%
\ifpgfrememberpicturepositiononpage%
\edef\pgf@temp{%
\noexpand\write\noexpand\pgfutil@auxout{%
\string\savepicturepage{\pgfpictureid}{\the\value{page}}}}%
\pgf@temp
\fi%
},
},
save picture id/.code={%
\immediate\write\pgfutil@auxout{%
\string\savepointas{#1}{\pgfpictureid}}%
},
if picture id/.code args={#1#2#3}{%
\@ifundefined{save@pt@#1}{%
\pgfkeysalso{#3}%
}{
\pgfkeysalso{#2}%
}
},
next page/.is choice,
next page vector/.initial={\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}},
next page/below/.style={%
next page vector={\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-\the\paperheight}}%
},
next page/above/.style={%
next page vector={\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\the\paperheight}}%
},
next page/left/.style={%
next page vector={\pgfqpoint{-\the\paperwidth}{0pt}}%
},
next page/right/.style={%
next page vector={\pgfqpoint{\the\paperwidth}{0pt}}%
},
next page/ignore/.style={%
next page vector={\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}%
},
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test} 

foo\tikzmark{foo}

\vspace{2cm}

bar\tikzmark{bar}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
   \draw (pic cs:foo) -- (pic cs:bar); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @PhilippImhof Please see my updated answer. In fact, there's a problem in `tikzmark` library using `\thepage`. I've provided a fix and will notify the author of the library.

Comment: Great, thank you. Just a question regarding what you wrote in your first answer: Why should one care about the bounding box when drawing just an overlay arrow? (I normally use the order you suggested, but I still wonder.)

Comment: @PhilippImhof You're welcome. I was confused when I posted my first answer. I already wrote to the library author alerting him about this.

Comment: The code isn't correct. The value of the page counter is not expanded. The aux contains `\savepicturepage{pgfid1}{\c@page }`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You're right. Thank you for noticing it. I've changed to `\the\value{page}`. At least this produces the value for the page in the `.aux` file, but I am not sure if this is the better approach. I've already written an email to Andrew Stacey about this, so surely he'll suggest the best fix here.

Comment: I'm not sure how important it is that the page value is unique (with \value{page} there is a (larger) danger of duplicates e.g. in books with a frontmatter. But probably it matters only if one use the same label.

Answer (score 2):

The page number is used for sorting and referring to the marked position. However, `chappg` changes the page number, such as from 1 to 1-1. The error comes, because that's not a number any more.

You can verify it by

```
\renewcommand*{\chappgsep}{0}
```

It will work then, because it's number.

Without going further in the depth, I would say it's a bug, because it already fails with roman page numbering:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{document}
foo\tikzmark{foo}

bar\tikzmark{bar}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
   \draw (pic cs:foo) -- (pic cs:bar); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Also this brings:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   i
l.10    \draw (pic cs:foo)
                           -- (pic cs:bar);
```

So it's independent of `chappg`.

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware that the page number was actually being used for this, but with that knowledge in mind, the problem becomes obvious.